# VueJS обработка одного маршрута разными компонентами

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Подскажите, как правильнее реализовать следующее. Есть мартшрут "/"
для неавторизованных пользователей он должен обрабатываться компонентом A, а для авторизованных компонентом B, можно ли это как-то сделать на уровне самого роутера, а не в компонентах через if ?

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть здесь: https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81n%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2